# how to create a loop for a macro in stata?

Tags: loops, macros, stata

I have a very large dataset but to cut it short I demonstrated the data with the following example:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input float(patid death dateofdeath)
 1 0     .
 2 0     .
 3 0     .
 4 0     .
 5 1 15007
 6 0     .
 7 0     .
 8 1 15526
 9 0     .
10 0     .
end
format %d dateofdeath
```

I am trying to sample for a case-control study based on date of death. At this stage, I need to first create a variable with each date of death repeated for all the participants (hence we end up with a dataset with 20 participants) and a `pairid` equivalent to the patient id `patid` of the corresponding case.

I created a macro for one case (which works) but I am finding it difficult to have it repeated for all cases (where `death==1`) in a loop.

The successful macro is as follows:

```
local i "5" //patient id who died 
     
gen pairid= `i'
gen matchedindexdate = dateofdeath
replace matchedindexdate=0 if pairid != patid
gsort matchedindexdate
replace matchedindexdate= matchedindexdate[_N]
format matchedindexdate %d
save temp`i'
```

and the loop I attempted is:

```
* (min and max patid id)     
forval j = 1/10  {
    count if patid == `j' & death==1
    if r(N)=1 {
        gen pairid= `j'
        gen matchedindexdate = dateofdeath
        replace matchedindexdate=0 if pairid != patid
        gsort matchedindexdate
        replace matchedindexdate= matchedindexdate[_N]
        save temp/matched`j'
    }
}

use temp/matched1, clear
forval i=2/10 {
    capture append using temp/matched`i'
    save matched, replace
}
```

but I get:

```
invalid syntax
```

How can I do the loop?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1591811-how-to-create-a-loop-for-a-macro

Comment: `if r(N) = 1` is the immediate bug. Should be `==`.

Comment: Good that you solved the problem. Now the key question is whether this thread will benefit others in the future. As I doubt that, I suggest deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had it solved, please check:

https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1591811-how-to-create-a-loop-for-a-macro